# Android interface becomes null

Tags: android, interface

I have a problem with an interface. I init the interface in an activity: `map.setFloorInterface(this);`

---

This is the method itself:

```
public void floorChanged(View view, int floorId) {
    map = (MapView) view.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.map, tView);
    map.setFloorInterface(this);
}
```

I'm trying to reset the interface because it's null the second time. The interface is called from a library I made, and is fired when I press a button.

---

Anyone has a clue why the interface does work the first time, but is null the second time?

Error log:

```
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at com.labela.blicks.Map$4.onClick(TiledScrollView.java:108)
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-05 16:34:55.273: E/AndroidRuntime(10288):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Maybe  the library interface put the this object to null?

Comment: An interface *can't be null*. Only an instance of an object, implementing that particular interface can be null.

Comment: The library does nothing more than creating the interface and triggering it when the user presses a button, so I don't know why it becomes null. In my library when the button is pressed I check the interface, it crashes because floorChanged is null

Comment: paste the error message that you are receiving.